# How to postpone a method to be done after each save() in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-celery

I'm using Django 1.8.4. There's a `Link` model which lets user to add a link to a website. Then I use `pyfav` to fetch the favicon from the inserted URL. I call get_favicon_url method in my `save()` method, so it cause an almost long waiting to do this task to save the object and redirect to success URL.

models.py

```
from pyfav import get_favicon_url

class Link(models.Model):
    url         = models.URLField("URL")
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.favicon = get_favicon_url(self.url)
        super(Link, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now I'm looking for a way to postpone `self.favicon = get_favicon_url(self.url)` to be done after the link has been saved and redirected to the success view since it's not a very important field to be filled and it could be done in background few seconds after the link has been saved.

Is this kind of job to be done with Celery? If so any hints to how to implement it would be appreciated since I don't have any experience with it.

Comment: Celery has docs to use it with Django http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a task scheduler like [Celery](http://celeryproject.org) with a task queue and delay the processing of the favicon.

I have done a python decorator for this http://mpcabd.igeex.biz/python-celery-asynchronous-task-decorator/ which can help you understanding how this works and if you use this decorator you can make your code clear and won't repeat it IMHO.

Comment: Would you add some codes to show the general structure of the models and views after Celery added?

Comment: Sure I added a link to a blog post I've done about this before, and the Celery website which is also linked is full of examples that are really easy to follow :)

Comment: The link posted by you is down @mpcabd